# Using HTML in a Zend_Form_Element description decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

Is it Possible to use HTML within a description decorator in a Zend_Form_Elment? For Example the following statement doesn't work:

```
$number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('number', array(
       'size' => 32,
       'description' => 'Please the the following website: <a href="foo/bar">lorem ipsum</a>',
       'max_length' => 100,
       'label' => 'Number'));
```

The link is not shown in the description, the brackets are converted into their special-char counterparts.

Is there another way to show a link (or use HTML at all...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, you just have to tell the `Description` decorator not to escape output.

Try:

```
$number = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('number', array(
   'size'        => 32,
   'description' => 'Please the the following website: <a href="foo/bar">lorem ipsum</a>',
   'max_length'  => 100,
   'label'       => 'Number')
);

$number->getDecorator('Description')->setOption('escape', false);
```

If you create your own set of decorators for elements, you can also specify this option when configuring decorators like this:

```
    $elementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('Description', array('class' => 'description', 'escape' => false)),
        array('HtmlTag',     array('class' => 'form-div')),
        array('Label',       array('class' => 'form-label', 'requiredSuffix' => '*'))
);
```

The relevant part being:

> array('Description', array('class' => 'description', **'escape' =>
>   false**)),